# How would I write JavaScript that accounts for multiple radio buttons and variable out comes depending on what radio button were selected?

Tags: javascript, html

Like the title says I'm trying to write JavaScript that accounts for multiple radio buttons(`<input type="radio">`) and variable out comes depending on what radio button were selected and then displaying the results upon request of a html `<button>`. I have been researching trying to find JavaScript code that would suite what I'm trying to do and so far this is what I've found:
    var myFunc = function () {
        alert('1');
    };

```
myFunc(); // alerts '1'

var myFunc = function () {
    alert('2');  
};

myFunc(); // alerts '2'
```

and

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="PASSED!";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

and

```
var checked = false, radios = document.getElementsById('radiogroup1');
for (var i = 0, radio; radio = radios[i]; i++) {
    if (radio.checked) {
        checked = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!checked) {
    alert("Please select option one");
    radios.focus();
    return false;
}

return true;
```

. I then went about trying to put it all together into a functional code and got this:

```
`<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var myFunc = function ('1') {
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass1');
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass2');
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass3');
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass4');
    for (var i = 0, radio; radio = radios[i]; i++) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            checked = true;
            document.getElementById('pass_fail_').innerHTML="PASSED!";
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!checked) {
        alert("Please select all options");
        radios.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
    break;

    var myFunc = function ('2') {
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass1');
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass2');
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass3');
        var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_fail4');
    for (var i = 0, radio; radio = radios[i]; i++) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            checked = true;
            document.getElementById('pass_fail_').innerHTML="PASSED!";
            break;
        }

    }

    if (!checked) {
        alert("Please select all options");
        radios.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
    break;

 myFunc('1); // function '1', function '2', function '3', function '4',            function '5', function '6', function '7', function '8', function '9', function '10', function '11', function '12', function '13', function '14', function '15', function '16'        </script>                           
`</head>
`<body>
    <p><b>Important Text</b></p>
    </br>
    <form id="_form_3">
        <input type="radio" name="grade" id="_pass3" value="pass"><font color="green">Pass</font></br>
        <input type="radio" name="grade" id="_fail3" value="fail"><font color="red">Fail</font>
    </form>
    <p>COmments</p>
    <textarea cols="95" rows="15">
    </textarea>
    </br>
    <hr>
    <p><b>Step, Slide, Switch</b><p>
    </br>
    <form id="_form_4">
        <input type="radio" name="grade" id="_pass4" value="pass"><font color="green">Pass</font></br>
        <input type="radio" name="grade" id="_fail4" value="fail"><font color="red">Fail</font>
     </form>
     <p>Comments</p>
     <textarea cols="95" rows="15">
     </textarea>
     </br>
     <hr>
     </form>
     <button onclick="myFunc('1')">PRESSS ME!</button>
     <p id="pass_fail_"></p>
`</body>
 `</html>
```

Now this didn't work and is obviously missing some parts that I withheld to try and limit your eye strain (all parts left out follow along similar line of what was shared) but whether it was a failing on JavaScripts part or my coding skills, leaning towards the latter, I don't know. Like the title says I'm trying to write JavaScript that accounts for multiple radio buttons(`<input type="radio">`) and variable out comes depending on what radio button were selected and then displaying the results upon request of a html `<button>`and I have a second question that pertains to the first. Can JavaScript run a well script to do what I'm trying to do or should I be using flash, or a .net language?

Comment: Wow! That is a lot of errors!

Answer (score 2):

When starting out, it's a good idea to write one or two lines of code and get them working. Then incrementally add more code, test and get them working. Writing slabs of non–working code is not an efficient approach.

Some comments:

```
> var myFunc = function () {
>   alert('1');
> };
```

I don't understand why function expressions are used when function declarations are available and more reliable.

```
function myFunc() {...}
```

Then there's:

```
> var checked = false, radios = document.getElementsById('radiogroup1');
```

The method you seek is `document.getElementById`, note singular, not plural. If you have a set of radio buttons with the same **name**, then you can use:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
```

or if they are in a form:

```
var radios = document.forms[n][name];
```

and

```
> var myFunc = function ('2') {
```

The formal parameter list must consist of zero or more valid identifiers, that isn't one. Identifiers can't be string literals nor start with a number. And use a function declaration:

```
function myFunc (a2) {
  ... 
}
```

Then here:

```
> var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass1');
> var checked = false, radios = document.getElementById('_pass2');
```

Here you are assigning values to the same variables, *checked* and *radios* will have a value of whatever the last assignment to them assigns.

```
>    if (radio.checked) {
>        checked = true;
>        document.getElementById('pass_fail_').innerHTML="PASSED!";
>        break;
>    }
```

Here you can remove the *checked* variable and *break* statement and simply return true, then you don't need the following *if* since it will only be reached if *checked* is false.

```
    if (radio.checked) {
      document.getElementById('pass_fail_').innerHTML="PASSED!";
      return true;
    }

    alert("Please select all options");
    radios.focus();
    return false;
```